# how to call setter from another module in python

Tags: python, module, getter-setter

I'm new to Python, I want to call a getter from another module

**menu.py**

```
class settings(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fbType=None

    @property
    def fbType(self):
        return self.fbType
    @fbType.setter
    def fbType(self, value):
        self.fbType = value

def main():
    print(20 * '-')
    print('   M E N U')
    print(30 * '-')
    print('1. page')
    print('2. event')
    print(20 * '-')

    choice = input('Enter your choice [1-5] : ')
    choice = int(choice)

    if choice == 1:
        fbType = 'page'
    elif choice == 2:
        fbType = 'event'
    else:
        print('seleccion incorrecta')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**fb.py**

```
import menu
from menu import settings

def main():
    menu.main()
    m = settings()
    l1 = fb.data(m.fbType(), 'python', 1)
    print(l1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error that is giving me is the following

```
File "C:\Users\gabri\PycharmProjects\borrar\menu.py", line 10, in fbType
self.fbType = value
[Previous line repeated 493 more times]
```

Please, could you give me a hand with the error? Thanks in advance

Comment: You have two attributes called `fbType`.  I suggest you rename one, for example:  `self._fbType = value`

Comment: I hope you understand that (in their current form) the getter and setter here are not needed at all.  Sometimes folks coming to python from places like java-land create un-needed getters and setters.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution you sent me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix for your code with :

```
class settings(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._fbType = None

    @property
    def fbType(self):
        return self._fbType

    @fbType.setter
    def fbType(self, value):
        self._fbType = value
```

Else **/!\ infinite loop**, here:

```
class settings(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fbType = None

    @property
    def fbType(self):
        return self.fbType

    @fbType.setter
    def fbType(self, value):
        self.fbType = value

m = settings()
m.fbType = 1
```

Output:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

With you call `def fbType(self, value)` it is a infinite loop, `self.fbType = value` call again the setter .... again and again ...

Do :

```
m.fbType # not m.fbType() to get
m.fbType = 1 # not m.fbType(1) to set
```

These getter and setter in python serve to do only treatment before or after
getter or setter (or to rename a attribute _fbType by fbType for example).

You can do :

```
class settings(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._fbType = None

    @property
    def fbType(self):
        print('get fbType:', self._fbType)
        return self._fbType

    @fbType.setter
    def fbType(self, value):
        print('set fbType:', self._fbType, 'to', value)
        self._fbType = value

m = settings()
m.fbType = 1
m.fbType
```

Output:

```
set fbType: None to 1
get fbType: 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution you sent me

Comment: A question: when I call m.fbType in fb.py it always returns None, why?

Comment: It is your constructor class settings(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fbType=None

Comment: If I run menu.py it works fine, but when I run fb.py it returns None `menu.main ()
m = settings ()
m.fbType`
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: change your constructor ;)

Comment: `class settings(object): def __init__(self): self.fbType = 1` it will return 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147550/discussion-between-gabriel-sule-and-glegoux).